# ¿Como hago para redirigir todo el tráfico a https?

Tags: .htaccess, https

Un amigo me ha hecho un sitio web en react con múltiples página sin cargar, cuando accedía a través del url obtenía un error 404, sin embargo esto ya lo solucioné con `.htaccess`.

El siguiente código y funciona.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Force everything through the index.php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

El problema ahora es ¿como hago para redirigir todo el tráfico a https?
Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para forzar que la redirección del tráfico a `HTTPS` puedes hacerlo así:

- (Opcional) Validamos que no estemos en el entorno de desarrollo (`eg: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost(:\d+)?$`)
- Controlamos si están utilizando `HTTP` (`eg: RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on`)
- Si lo anterior se cumple, redirigimos reescribiendo la `URL` con protocolo `HTTPs` (`eg: RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`)

#### Ejemplo:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirección a HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost(:\d+)?$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirección URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```